# Duplicate breadcrumbs in catalog_product_view.xml

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, breadcrumbs

I am trying to duplicate breadcrumbs in product page, as so to be able to hide and show it in different positions for mobile and desktop devices. I have tried the following but breadcrumb shows only once in prodcut page above product.info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />
<move element="breadcrumbs2" destination="content" before="-" />
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs2" as="breadcrumbs2"/>
</referenceContainer>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override below file to your theme

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\breadcrumbs.phtml

add code as below

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs $block */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
?>
<div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
<div class="breadcrumbs_second"></div>

<?php
$widget = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonDecode($viewModel->getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped());
$widgetOptions = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($widget['breadcrumbs']);
?>


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".breadcrumbs": {
            "breadcrumbs": <?= /* @noEscape */ $widgetOptions ?>
        }
    }
</script>


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".breadcrumbs_second": {
            "breadcrumbs": <?= /* @noEscape */ $widgetOptions ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That seems to work creating two divs but in the second one breadcrumb_second I get duplicate the category and product link.
   ' <li class="item category">
        
        <a>Bracelets</a>
        
    </li>

    <li class="item product">
        
        <strong>Personalize Super Duper Bracelet</strong>
        
    </li>

    <li class="item category">
        
        <a>Bracelets</a>
        
    </li>

    <li class="item product">
        
        <strong>Personalize Super Duper Bracelet</strong>
        
    </li>'

Comment: please add css(media query) based on your requirement.